# ¿Cómo servir archivos estáticos desde una aplicación?

Tags: python, django

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación usando **Django 1.9.2** y **Python 3.5.1**, pero me encuentro con un problema al tratar de configurar el proyecto y ajustar el tema del *frontend*.

Los archivos estáticos del tema están dentro de la aplicación, pero el módulo `django.contrib.staticfiles` encargado de *servir* los archivos estáticos no los encuentra.

#### Configuración

Esta es la parte de la configuración de archivos estáticos. La aplicación `core` es donde está la configuración y proporciona elementos comunes. La aplicación `jit` es la que estoy desarrollando.

```
from unipath import Path

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR.child("assets")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'jit/assets',
)

INSTALLED_APPS += [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core',
    'jit'
]
```

Esta es la estructura de los directorios

```
src
├── assets
│   ├── css
│   ├── fonts
│   └── js
├── bower_components
├── core
├── data
├── jit
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   └── js
│   ├── migrations
│   └── templates
├── node_modules
└── tema
    └── sass
```

#### Patrones de URL

Este es el archivo de patrones de búsqueda de URL `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static, url
from jit import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

#### La Vista

La vista no podría ser más sencilla.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'jit/index.html')
```

#### La plantilla

La plantilla es, igualmente, muy simple:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Justo a Tiempo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'jit/css/jit.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="{% static 'jit/js/jit.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### El error

El error aparece cuando uso `{% static 'jit/css/jit.css' %}` porque no aparece cuando uso `{% static 'css/jit.css' %}`. Los archivos existen en ambos directorios.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/static/jit/css/jit.css
Raised by:  django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve
'jit/css/jit.css' could not be found
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

> Estoy *casi* seguro que esta configuración funciona en la computadora de mi trabajo, donde uso Python 3.4. En cualquier caso, agradecería que me hiciera ver mi error.

Comment: ¿Por qué aparecería algo si usas `{% static 'jit/css/jit.css' %}`?, esa ruta no existe en tus estáticos

Comment: Si existe, lo configure en la `STATICFILES_DIRS`

Comment: En tus `STATICFILES_DIRS` solo tienes `'jit/assets'`, por lo tanto solo puedes usar `{% static 'css/.. %}`, `{% static 'fonts/.. %}` y `{% static 'js/.. %}`, nada mas

Comment: Comprendo, tendría que eliminar la parte de `jit`. Gracias.

Comment: Correcto, estoy creando una respuesta para que quede mas claro

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias @César. El problema está en la estructura de directorio que generaba `gulp`. Para que funcione como espero los _assets_ deben estar en `jit/assets/jit/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bien, vamos por partes:

```
STATIC_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR.child("assets")
```

La carpeta `STATIC_ROOT` va a contener los archivos que se copiarán cuando pases a producción y ejecutes el comando [`collectstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic). No es necesario que crees esta estructura de carpetas en `assets`:

```
src
├── assets
│   ├── css
│   ├── fonts
│   └── js
```

Esto lo crea automáticamente Django al ejecutar `collectstatic`. Incluso ni siquiera es necesario que la carpeta se encuentre dentro del proyecto, puedes pasarle una ruta como:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/static/'
```

Bien, eso con respecto a los estáticos en producción. Ahora con respecto a [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs):

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'jit/assets',
)
```

Todas estas carpetas le indican a Djando donde buscar los archivos estáticos (también es usado por el comando `collectstatic`), por lo tanto y según tu estructura:

```
src
├── ...
├── jit
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   └── js
│   ├── migrations
│   └── templates
├── ...
```

Solo tendrías acceso a las siguientes rutas:

- `jit/assets/css`
- `jit/assets/fonts`
- `jit/assets/js`

En el template, respectivamente esto es como usar:

- `{% static 'css/foo.css' %}`
- `{% static 'fonts/foo.woff2' %}`
- `{% static 'js/foo.js' %}`

Como ves, no hay opción para `{% static 'jit/css/jit.css' %}` ya que no existe esa la carpeta `jit/assets/jit`. Si el proceso de Gulp los pone en otra ruta simplemente agrégala o cámbiala:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'jit/assets/jit',
)
```

Para poder tener acceso a:

- `jit/assets/jit/css`
- `jit/assets/jit/fonts`
- `jit/assets/jit/js`

Comment: Efectivamente.  La ruta correcta para colocar los archivos estáticos y que funcionen de la forma en que planteo es `jit/assets/jit` y la configuración de `STATICFILES_DIR` queda tal cual la planteé inicialmente.